# SSO federated logout on Auth0 not working as expected

Tags: gmail, single-sign-on, auth0, logout

I have an app where I need to be able to log a user out so that they can log back in.

To log the user out, I am making a call to:

```
https://<domain>/v2/logout?client_id=<clientId>&returnTo=<redirectUri>&federated
```

The issue is that instead of getting a `302` as expected and having the user logged out of their SSO, sometimes the call returns an `OK` with a `200` status and signs the user back in.

I am aware of this issue with Auth0, as per this [Auth0 community post](https://community.auth0.com/t/log-out-doesnt-work-and-automatically-sign-in/14826) but passing the `client_id` and the `returnTo` parameters was supposed to handle it.

This happens with a Google account and it seems that the user is indeed logged out of Auth0 but not actually from the SSO provider.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this again, I believe the answer is actually pretty simple.

The behavior described above happens when someone tries to perform a `logout` using the `v2/logout` url, while not having an active Auth0 session.

The end-point will not flag this but instead will respond with either a `200` or a `302` without additional actions.